# Hyperlinking value of one cell to another

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

This is my current code

```
foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
  if($key=='MobileNumber'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?MobileNumber=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
  elseif($key=='TeamGroup'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?TeamGroup=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
  elseif($key=='OCU'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?OCU=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
  else{print "<td>$value</td>";}
}
```

So I want to make it so that if `$key=='FirstName'` then it will make `$value` the value of the `MobileNumber` instead of the `FirstName`.

For example say then I click on the hyperlink on the name Andy, then it will take me to Test.php/MobileNumber=07252148203

I just don't know how to reference another column.

I am using MySQL for my tables.

Comment: Please use print_r($row) and tell what is the output.

Comment: Array ( [FirstName] => Andy [Surname] => Dawson [MobileNumber] => 07252148203 [CallSign] => 234 [TeamGroup] => LS [OCU] => OCU1 )

Comment: Answer given by @clami219 will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
  if($key=='MobileNumber'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?MobileNumber=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
  elseif($key=='TeamGroup'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?TeamGroup=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
  elseif($key=='OCU'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?OCU=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
  elseif($key=='FirstName'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?MobileNumber=".$row['MobileNumber']."'>$value</a></td>";}
  else{print "<td>$value</td>";}
}
```